# How can I assign a List<int> value of a map to a list outside of that map?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need a list of my map assigned to a List variable outside of this map. How can I do that?

```
class Lists { 
  late var list = Map<int, List<int>>();
  Lists() {
    list[0] = [];
    list[1] = [];
    list[2] = [];
    list[3] = [];
  }
}
```

In another file I then try to assign the list[0] to a List variable:

```
List<int> listOutside = Lists.list[0];
```

I then receive this error:[image]

What does the "?" mean and how can I fix that?

Thanks for the help.

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 major problems that are there.

1. You are trying to access a static variable outside a class which is wrong. This problem can be fixed by adding `List<int> listOutside = Lists().list[0];` (notice the parentheses)
2. By accessing the `list[0];` you are saying that the element always exists but here the compiler comes into play saying that this is a nullable list (`List<int>?`) which you are trying to assign to `List<int>` which is not possible as both have different types. This problem can be quickly fixed by using `!` at the end `Lists().list[0]!;`

But note that this comes with a side effect that if there is no element at `0`the index then this will throw NPE.

**NOTE:** Always avoid using `!` in expressions where you are not sure that it is not nullable.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work when adding a "!".

```
List<int> listOutside = Lists.list[0]!;
```

I have no clue why, but anyways it works :D

Answer (score 0):

`?` means that this field can have the null value. The Dart language now supports sound null safety and to indicate that a variable might have the value `null`, just add `?` to its type declaration:

```dart
int? aNullableInt = null;
```

For your problem, you try to access list variable as a static usage and you use late but you initialize field immediately. For this reason, you can omit late and put static.

This usage could solve your problem:

```dart
static var list = Map<int, List<int>>();

List<int> listOutside = Lists.list[0];
```